# Paginação por demanda com Angular ou JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paginação

Como fazer uma paginação sob demanda com AngularJS? Eu tenho 2 particularidades:

1 - Não pode ser usado o jQuery, apenas o Angular ou JavaScript puro.

2 - Eu tenho 2 métodos o `prevPage` e `nextPage`.
Abaixo exemplo dos métodos:

```
 $scope.prevPage = function(page){
    if($scope.currentPage-1 > 0){
        $scope.changePage(page);
    }
}

$scope.nextPage = function(page){
    if($scope.currentPage+1 <= $scope.numberOfPages){
        $scope.changePage(page);
    }
}
```

Aqui, para ficar mais visível, tem o HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-click="prevPage(currentPage-1)" ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 1}"></li>
    <li ng-repeat="i in numberOfPagesArr track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index+1 == currentPage}" ng-click="changePage($index+1)">{{$index+1}}</li>
    <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-click="nextPage(currentPage+1)" ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == numberOfPages}"></li>
</ul>
```

Atualmente está funcionando, porém na página carrega somente 10 páginas de paginação,
mas se aumentar o número com certeza irá quebrar.

Aqui tem [um exemplo da paginação](http://begriffs.github.io/angular-paginate-anything/) em questão de como quero fazer.

Comment: O que você quer é a parte das reticências quando há muitas páginas?

Comment: Exatamente @bfavaretto!

Comment: Para marcar o bfavaretto no seu comentário use o @ antes do nome assim @bfavaretto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você precisa é o [Angular-UI](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). Dentre outros componentes ele disponibiliza o [Pagination](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination).

Veja o objetivo do projeto:

> Native AngularJS (Angular) directives for Bootstrap. Small footprint (5kB gzipped!), no 3rd party JS dependencies (jQuery, bootstrap JS) required!

Ou seje ele depende apenas do `bootstrap.css`. Toda a parte de comportamento dinâmico foi feita diretamente em JavaScript e Angular e não depende nem do jQuery nem do `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Obrigado @JoaoParana estava vendo esse projeto :) E terei que fazer algumas modificações, mas ajudou pakas vlw!

Answer (score 2):

```
var c = sualistaEmJson;
$scope.totalPorPagina = 10;
$scope.totalRegistro = c.length;
$scope.pagina = [];
var p = $scope.totalRegistro > $scope.totalPorPagina ? Math.ceil($scope.totalRegistro / $scope.totalPorPagina) : 1;
for (var i = 0; i < p; i++) {
     $scope.pagina.push(c.splice(0, $scope.totalPorPagina));
}
$scope.lista = $scope.pagina[0];
insira o código aqui
//função chamada no ngClick;
$scope.loadListPagination = function (i) {
        $scope.lista = $scope.pagina[i];
    };
//HTML fica assim
<div ng-repeat="x in lista">
{{x}}
</div>
<nav ng-show="totalPorPagina < totalRegistro">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li ng-repeat="p in pagina">
                <a href ng-click="loadListPagination($index)" style="background-color: #777;">
                    {{$index + 1}}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: A sua resposta ficaria mais completa se tivesse uma pequena introdução/explicação e não apenas o código.

Answer (score -2):

Aqui explico como fazer: https://guerrati.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/angularjs-paginacao-no-ng-repeat/

Basicamente é assim:

Utiliza o [dirPaginate](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination). Você precisa baixálo [aqui](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js), depois iniciá-lo na sua página:

```
<script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
```

E colocá-lo como dependência do seu módulo principal:

```
var app = angular.module('guerraTI', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Agora para ativar a paginação, basta substituir o ng-repeat pela diretiva dir-paginate. O único parâmetro que precisa ser adicionado é o itemsPerPage, que como o próprio nome já diz, é a quantidade de registros que serão mostrados em cada página.

```
<tr dir-paginate="dado in dados|filter:procurar|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|itemsPerPage:5">
```

Após isso, pode colocar os controles da paginação:

```
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
```